# Can't redefine \crefname for default counters

Tags: cleveref

I want to redefine cross-reference name for \subsection. That does work in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\crefname{subsection}{Punkt}{Punkte}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}\label{test}
\section{Test A}\label{testa}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Dummy-Text}\label{dummya}
\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Noch mehr}\label{dummyb}
\lipsum[3]

\section{Querverweis}\label{crossref}
\cref{dummya} in \cref{testa} (\cref{test}) ist irrelevant.
\end{document}
```

However, it does not work in my real document. There, I have moved this code:

```
\usepackage[ngerman,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{table}{Tab.}{Tab.}
\crefname{scheme}{Übersicht}{Übersichten}
\crefname{subsection}{Punkt}{Punkte}
```

immediately before \begin{document}. Nevertheless, \cref still precedes tables with "Tabelle"/"Tabellen" and subsections with "Abschnitt"/"Abschnitte" (apparently the German default value inherited from section). The strange thing is that the definitions for the type "scheme" are accepted. The only difference between table/subsection and scheme is that I defined the scheme-environment myself, while the others use default counters.

Does anybody have an idea what might be wrong?

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue. With your code I get: "Punkt 1.1.1 in Abschnitt 1.1 (Kapitel 1) ist irrelevant." in the pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use aliase:

```
\crefname{punkt}{Punkt}{Punkte}
\crefalias{subsection}{punkt}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[american,ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{tab}{Tab.}{Tab.}
\crefname{scheme}{Übersicht}{Übersichten}
\crefname{abschnitt}{Abschnitt}{Abschnitte}
\crefname{punkt}{Punkt}{Punkte}

\crefalias{section}{abschnitt}
\crefalias{subsection}{punkt}
\crefalias{table}{tab}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\chapter{Test}
\section{asdf}\label{sec}
\subsection{ghjk}\label{sub}
\begin{table}
\caption{A table}\label{tab}
\end{table}

\cref{sec,sub,tab} Plural der Namen: \namecrefs{sec}, \namecrefs{sub} und \namecrefs{tab} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond earlier. Nevertheless, \crefalias works like a charm! :-)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've minimized my MWE too much! Apparently, it was babel's fault. This version works:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american,main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{table}{Tab.}{Tab.}
\crefname{scheme}{Übersicht}{Übersichten}
\crefname{section}{Abschnitt}{Abschnitte}
\crefname{subsection}{Punkt}{Punkte}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\crefname{table}{Tab.}{Tab.}
\crefname{scheme}{Übersicht}{Übersichten}
\crefname{section}{Abschnitt}{Abschnitte}
\crefname{subsection}{Punkt}{Punkte}  

\chapter{Test}
\section{asdf}\label{sec}
\subsection{ghjk}\label{sub}
\begin{table}
\caption{A table}\label{tab}
\end{table}

\cref{sec,sub,tab}
\end{document}
```

Notice the `\selectlanguage{ngerman}`? This seems to turn on the default values for the default types/counters. Type "scheme" is a custom environment/counter, so it is not reset by `\selectlanguage{ngerman}`.

Strangely enough, it is not sufficient to define the crefnames after `\selectlanguage`! If the lines with `\crefname` are removed from the preamble (leaving just the duplicates after `\setlanguage`), the default values are used again:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american,main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\crefname{table}{Tab.}{Tab.}
\crefname{scheme}{Übersicht}{Übersichten}
\crefname{section}{Abschnitt}{Abschnitte}
\crefname{subsection}{Punkt}{Punkte}

\chapter{Test}
\section{asdf}\label{sec}
\subsection{ghjk}\label{sub}
\begin{table}
\caption{A table}\label{tab}
\end{table}

\cref{sec,sub,tab}
\end{document}
```